# Struts2.5.10.1 core jar missing xwork2 dispatcher package

Tags: struts2, xwork

I see the Struts2.5.10.1 core jar is missing the dispatcher package. I have the below code in my JSP and it does not work anymore. Could anyone answer me what would be the correct code to write here?

```
<s:set var="url" value="%{#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'].requestURL}"/>
```

**Answer**: Below is the code template used. I removed un-required code and replaced it with '...'.

The Result is that I got a complete link: http://localhost:8080/.../param1=val1&param2=val2

Comment: You're just trying to get the current request's URL?

Comment: yes. I guess I am.

Comment: It is not a class it is a constant. Just use `<s:url>` tag.

Comment: I could resolve the issue on my own. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Vikd Post your answer and accept it.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, I have  updated my question with the correct answer.

Comment: @Vikd If you scroll a little further down the page you'll see an answer section. Post your answer there.